# JQuery .change() method triggering when attached to an element who's data is changed dynamically

Tags: jquery, events, onchange

I have a JQuery slider. a line of code is changing the val property of an input box as the slider is moved.

I am trying to get the function to fire whenever the value of the input box is changed. However, it only fires when the user changes the value directly via clicking on the input box. Moving the slider does nothing.

Is there any way to get:

```
$('#element').change(function(){});
```

to fire when the data in element is changed indirectly?

Thanks

UPDATE:

This is the slider cod and the code that passes the value to the input box.

```
$(this).slider({
    range : true,
    max:projectStart,
    min:projectEnd,
    step:86400,
    values:[ end, begin ],
    slide : function(event,ui) {
      //if (ui.values[1]>startLimit) {
          //ui.values[1]=startLimit;
          //return false;
      //}
        var g = (this.id);
        $('#form-' + IDNum + '-StartDate').val(new Date(ui.values[1]*-1000).toDateString());
        $('#form-' + IDNum + '-EndDate').val(new Date(ui.values[0 ]*-1000).toDateString());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to trigger the change event when you change the value :

```
$('#form-' + IDNum + '-StartDate').val(new Date(ui.values[1]*-1000).toDateString()).trigger("change");
$('#form-' + IDNum + '-EndDate').val(new Date(ui.values[0 ]*-1000).toDateString()).trigger("change");
```

Or

```
$('#form-' + IDNum + '-StartDate').val(new Date(ui.values[1]*-1000).toDateString()).change();
$('#form-' + IDNum + '-EndDate').val(new Date(ui.values[0 ]*-1000).toDateString()).change();
```

Comment: Can you please expand on that. What do you mean "YourValue"?

Comment: You certainly have a function who is called when you move your slider which change the val of you input no ?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the value of any control programmatically, you must have to trigger `change` event explicitly.

There are two ways to do that in jquery. First by calling `change()` function on target control and other is calling `trigger("change")` function which accepts event name as parameter.

In your case, following will be work.

```
$(this).slider({
    range : true,
    max:projectStart,
    min:projectEnd,
    step:86400,
    values:[ end, begin ],
    slide : function(event,ui) {
        //if (ui.values[1]>startLimit) {
            //ui.values[1]=startLimit;
            //return false;
        //}
        var g = (this.id);
        $('#form-' + IDNum + '-StartDate').val(new Date(ui.values[1]*-1000).toDateString()).change(); //Trigger change event
        $('#form-' + IDNum + '-EndDate').val(new Date(ui.values[0 ]*-1000).toDateString()).change(); //Trigger change event
    }
});
```